# Can't enable AMD-V in VirtualBox (hardware virtualization)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, cpu, hardware-virtualization

In the VM settings, the case `VT-x / AMD-V` is grey and I can't check it. Why ?

- I have a Windows 10 pro host (updated)
- I use Vbox 6.1 (the latest)
- `SVM mode` is enabled in my BIOS settings
- Windows task manager says virtualization is enabled in the `performances` tab
- `AMD-V/Hyper-V Compatibility Checker` says `this machine is compatible with hyper-v`
- In the windows features (`enable or disable windows features...`), `hyper-v` is disabled, `containers` is disabled, `guarded host` is disabled
- In the Windows defender settings, the core and memory isolation is disabled.
- I rebooted many times

Any idea ?

[EDIT 26/05/2020]

I forgot to say :

- I have a ryzen 5 3600x
- My motherboard is a MSI B450M PRO M2 MAX

[EDIT 2 26/05/2020]

In order to answer `essjae` comment :

I haven't got any 3rd party antivirus. I just use Windows defender.

When I run `systeminfo`, I get the message `Hyper-V Requirements: A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.`. Considering this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo), it would mean Hyper-v is already running. But I don't understand why, because when I go in `Enable or disable Windows features`, Hyper-v is **unchecked** ! (I rebooted many times).

Also, here is the output of `coreinfo.exe` ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo))

```
> .\Coreinfo.exe

Coreinfo v3.5 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2020 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
AMD64 Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
Microcode signature: 00000000
HTT             *       Multicore
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM             -       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64             *       Supports 64-bit mode

SMX             -       Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT          -       Supports AMD SKINIT

NX              *       Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP            *       Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB         *       Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE             *       Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT             *       Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE             *       Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36           *       Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE             *       Supports global bit in page tables
SS              -       Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME             *       Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    *       Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU             *       Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT          *       Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW           -       Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT        -       Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE             *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3            *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3           *       Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4a           *       Supports Streaming SIMDR Extensions 4a
SSE4.1          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2          *       Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES             *       Supports AES extensions
AVX             *       Supports AVX instruction extensions
FMA             *       Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR             *       Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR            *       Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE           *       Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE         *       Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND          *       Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED          *       Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV            *       Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH           *       Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8             *       Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16            *       Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2            *       Supports bit manipulation extensions 2
ADX             *       Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA             -       Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C            *       Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR            *       Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR           *       Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR         -       Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE           *       Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB           -       Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLMULDQ        *       Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT          *       Supports POPCNT instruction
LZCNT           *       Supports LZCNT instruction
SEP             *       Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF       *       Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE             -       Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM             -       Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE              *       Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64          -       Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS              -       Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL          -       Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID            -       Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID         -       Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM            -       Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP          *       Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC             *       Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -       Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *       TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR            -       Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST            -       Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI            -       Implements MSR for power management
TM              -       Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2             -       Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC            *       Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC          -       Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID         -       L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE             *       Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA             *       Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE             -       Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN             -       Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW       *       Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Maximum implemented CPUID leaves: 0000000D (Basic), 8000001E (Extended).
Maximum implemented address width: 48 bits (virtual), 48 bits (physical).

Processor signature: 00870F10

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
**----------  Physical Processor 0 (Hyperthreaded)
--**--------  Physical Processor 1 (Hyperthreaded)
----**------  Physical Processor 2 (Hyperthreaded)
------**----  Physical Processor 3 (Hyperthreaded)
--------**--  Physical Processor 4 (Hyperthreaded)
----------**  Physical Processor 5 (Hyperthreaded)

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
************  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
************  NUMA Node 0

No NUMA nodes.

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
**----------  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**----------  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
**----------  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
******------  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,   16 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--**--------  Data Cache          1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**--------  Instruction Cache   1, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--**--------  Unified Cache       2, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**------  Data Cache          2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**------  Instruction Cache   2, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----**------  Unified Cache       3, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**----  Data Cache          3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**----  Instruction Cache   3, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------**----  Unified Cache       4, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
------******  Unified Cache       5, Level 3,   16 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64
--------**--  Data Cache          4, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**--  Instruction Cache   4, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
--------**--  Unified Cache       6, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**  Data Cache          5, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**  Instruction Cache   5, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
----------**  Unified Cache       7, Level 2,  512 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
************  Group 0
```

[EDIT 3 26/05/2020]

As `Ramhound` asked in the comments section, here is a screenshot of the option I can't check.

[image: Virtualbox screenshot]

Here is a picture of the `SVM mode` in my BIOS. Sorry for the bad quality.

[image: Picture of SVM mode]

I haven't got Github Desktop. I just use git bash.

You can find below a screenshot of my tasks manager.

[image: Tasks manager screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the windows features.

[image: Windows features screenshot]

[EDIT 4 26/05/2020]

Here is the result of `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *Hyper-V*` :

```
> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *Hyper-V*


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
DisplayName      : Hyper-V
Description      : Provides services and management tools for creating and running virtual machines and their
                   resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Platform
Description      : Provides the services that you can use to create and manage virtual machines and their resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Tools-All
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Management Tools
Description      : Includes GUI and command-line tools for managing Hyper-V.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell
Description      : Includes Windows PowerShell cmdlets for managing Hyper-V.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Hypervisor
Description      : Provides the Hyper-V Hypervisor.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services
DisplayName      : Hyper-V Services
Description      : Provides the services that you can use to create and manage virtual machines and their resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients
DisplayName      : Hyper-V GUI Management Tools
Description      : Includes the Hyper-V Manager snap-in and Virtual Machine Connection tool.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :
```

Here is the result of `@(Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent` :

```
> @(Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent
True
```

[EDIT 5 30/05/2020]

I tried to enable hw virt manually with the command `.\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "110-proxy-ub-2004" --nested-hw-virt on`, but I get this error when I try to start the VM :

[image: Hw virt manually enabled]

I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Even if `Hyper-v` was disabled in the `Windows features`, the service named `HV Host Service` was still running. I disabled all the `Hyper-v` services and now the option `VT-x / AMD-V` in the Vbox VM setting isn't grayed out anymore and my VM boots when I enable the option.

[image: services]

Comment: I disabled all those and stopped services but still can't enable AMD-V.

Comment: I found that run this command can help > https://stackoverflow.com/a/56973830/128761
`$ VBoxManage modifyvm vm-name --nested-hw-virt on`

Comment: @vee your link is the correct answer!