# In Oracle VirtualBox how do I disable hardware virtualization?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

The settings menu says "Invalid Settings Detected." When I hover over it, it states the following:

> System: Acceleration Page: The hardware virtualization is enabled in
> the Acceleration section of the System page although it is not
> supported by the host system. It should be disabled to start the
> virtual system.

There is no option I can change to turn this off, and none of the options work to fix the error.

[image]

I'm using the newest version of Windows 10 and VirtualBox. VirtualBox did not patch this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't enable AMD-V in VirtualBox (hardware virtualization)](https://superuser.com/questions/1555293/cant-enable-amd-v-in-virtualbox-hardware-virtualization)

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to create a 64-bit VM? This requires hardware virtualization. // If you can, you should enable hardware virtualization though. It offers much better performance. All modern hardware should support it.

Comment: @Daniel B I'm not sure how to check, but I gave it 32MB of RAM. (I'm trying to run DOS)

Comment: If the Hyper-V Windows feature is enabled on your computer, it may conflict with VirtualBox.

Comment: Current version of VirtualBox does not conflict with Hyper-V being enabled provided the author is running a supported version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears VirtualBox no longer exposes this setting in the user interface.

As mentioned in my comment, the real solution is to enable hardware-assisted virtualization for your PC. It not only offers much improved performance but is also required for 64-bit guests. Barring broken BIOS/UEFI implementations, any modern system should support Intel VT-x or AMD-V (previously AMD SVM).

---

You can still modify the setting using `VBoxManage`, like this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VM Name> --hwvirtex off
```

As you discovered, `VBoxManage` is not in `%PATH%` by default on Windows, so you need to either specify the full path to it or `cd %ProgramFiles%\Oracle\VirtualBox` first to use it.

You also need to disable Nested Paging if it is still enabled (because it implies hardware-assisted virtualization), so the full command could be:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <VM Name> --hwvirtex off --nestedpaging off
```

You cannot use 64-bit guests with these settings. However, 16-bit and 32-bit guests will work. Make sure to select the correct guest OS.

There are many more settings. If you’re interested in better understanding VirtualBox, I suggest reading the [great manual on `VBoxManage`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html). You can do awesome stuff like hot-swapping virtual hard drives and whatnot.

Comment: The author can confirm that the problem is linked to hardware virtualization being enabled within the configuration for the VM, by looking at the generated log, and looking for messages with regards to the Hardware Acceleration Manager (HM). [VirtualBox Manual - Chapter 10.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt) explains the reason hardware virtualization is enabled out of the box.  I had the same thoughts, but it was difficult to debug, since basic information about VM was left unknown even after a chat.

Comment: To be clear the VM configuration has it enabled, but it's not enabled for the host OS, thus the error with regards to the configuration.  VirtualBox not allowing you to make configuration changes while a configuration error exist isn't a new issue.